# Strange indexing behavior UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionView with 64 items. A user can tap on a variety of options in the screen before and my goal is to load this carousel to the index/item the user selected.

We show 3 items on the screen at the same time with their selection being centered.

So if the user selects item 8 from the previous screen, when we push, I'd like the collection view to be on item 8 and they'll still see 7 and 9 on the screen on the sides.

All of this is working but I'm getting some weird paging behavior.

In `viewDidAppear`:

```
carousel.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: selectedId, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
carousel.reloadData()
```

But when I page left or right, it always seems to be on the 1st index rather than the one the user selected.

Any clue as to what I'm doing incorrectly here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you need to reload your data before selecting an item.
Also maybe try: 
`scrollToItem(at: selectedItemIndexPath, at: .center, animated: false)`